# Change font style of textview on listitem is click?

Tags: android

How to set textview font Style on click of listvite item is clicked. if i select first item from list then my textview fontstye1 and then when i select second or third item from list at that time change my textview fontstyle2 or fontstyle3.

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fontstyle1");
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fontstyle2");
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fontstyle3");
txtView.setTypeface(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to set textview font Style on click of listvite item is clicked

Use `onItemClick`  to change text color of selected row:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
      {
           TextView txtView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview_id);
           Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(view.getContext().getAssets(),
                                                         "fontstyle"+(position+1)); 
           txtView.setTypeface(type);   
    }});
```

Comment: you r right but i want to do this on arraylist if i select first item at that time change font as first titem then if i select second item from arraylist at that time change font as second font.... did u got wat i m try to tell you